# ADB Command to disable Don't Keep Acitivites

Tags: android, adb

Is there an ADB command which I can disable the Don't Keep Activities option under Developer Options?

Couldn't find any commands to that online.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
adb shell settings put global always_finish_activities 0
```

0: Off

1: On

Then you can check it with this:

```
adb shell settings get global always_finish_activities
```